Better way to keep dimensions using reshape from struct array in matlab
I am wondering what is the best way to extract the data from an structured array in matlab and keeping is dimensionality if I use reshape while processing it.
Let's say I have the following struct array

In order to extract all b values I would do
K>> [myData.data(:).b]

ans =

   20.0183   19.8833   20.0183   19.8833   20.0182   19.8833   20.0183   19.8833   20.0182   19.8833

But this rises the issue that the dimensionality of b is lost, since now it is treated as an vector. If I do reshape to try to recover that dimensionality I will get
bb=reshape([myData.data(:).b]',[],2)

bb =

   20.0183   19.8833
   19.8833   20.0183
   20.0183   19.8833
   19.8833   20.0182
   20.0182   19.8833

which is still not the original data, because all even row are swapped. So the only thing I came up was to undo that swapping on even rows via
K>> bb(2:2:end,:) = fliplr(bb(2:2:end,:))

bb =

   20.0183   19.8833
   20.0183   19.8833
   20.0183   19.8833
   20.0182   19.8833
   20.0182   19.8833
 

Hence I wonder whether there exists a better way to extract b from the struct array without having to do the reshape + even elemen flip.
Thanks in advance!

I don’t understand how those rows could possibly get swapped. That makes no sense.

You can use vertcat instead of [...]:
bb = vertcat(myData.data(:).b);


For OP: it might help to understand why this works by seeing that [...] is simply shorthand for vertcat's oft-overlooked sibling horzcat(...). i.e. you're currently using horzcat to concatonate horizontally, simply use vertcat to concatenate vertically
